# Port forwarding not working on my computer

Tags: apache, port, portforwarding

So I have been having this issue for a while... I tried to portforward my apache webserver using port 80 with my computers IP address (192.168.0.3). It lets me enter the details but when I use http://www.canyouseeme.org/ to check if the port is open it says it is not. I then tried port forwarding another machine on my network (192.168.0.4) and when I checked using canyouseeme it said the port was open. I think my pc is blocking the forwarding of my port? The problem arose when  I used to use peer block but don't anymore - I was wondering if this could be the cause of my problem? I can connect to my apache server via localhost on the host machine but not using other pc's on my network.

If you need anymore information please ask - I would like to sort this out even if it means manually reopening ports on my firewall (which I've tried...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check your personal firewall settings or, when using Windows, your AntiVirus settings.